# Can you type alias an existing user-defined type in C?

Tags: c, types

Say I want to define two structs, the first one has a type, and the other I want to be of the same type as the first. Is this possible in C99?

Example:

```
typedef struct {
    fieldA;
    fieldB;
} typeA;


struct B {
    fieldA
    fieldB
};
```

`typedef B A;`

If not typedef, is there another keyword/way to do this?

Edit: It seems I wasn't being as clear as possible, judging from the feedback so far (which I greatly appreciate!)

My specific scenario is a typedef struct definition that is required to type alias another struct.

Comment: You don't need the extra struct. Just `typedef typeA B;` should do what (I think) you're asking.

Comment: I'm confused.  Your example code appears intended to declare two struct *types* (but is not syntactically correct).  It does not declare any objects having those types.  Are you just asking how to write a typedef for a struct type?

Comment: Once you declare a struct type, whether you typedef it or not, you can declare as many objects of that type as you like.

Comment: `typedef B A;` There is no type `B` in your example, thus this typedef makes no sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: No, that's not possible. At least not with any ISO-C standard.

Long answer: Struct types are a compile time construct, not a runtime construct. At runtime a struct is just a bunch of bytes on the stack or heap and code accessing struct fields is just accessing values of certain length at a certain offset (the code only knows how many bytes to fetch from which offset from the beginning of the struct). The structure itself is not stored in the compiled code at all.

So any code that can deal with `typeA` would equally be able to deal with `struct B`, as they are the same in memory but at compile time the compiler will enforce that they are different types, since C types are not defined by "how they look" but only by their name. And a `typedef` just sets an alternative name for a given type.

The logic behind types being defined by name is, while this technically is the same value in memory:

```
struct IPAddress { uint32_t addr; };
struct Count { uint32_t count; };
```

it's still not an interchangeable type, as one is a counter value and one is an IP address and you should not ever pass one to a function expecting the other one. If both types really mean the same thing, why having two types to begin with? So I guess what you are going for is inheritance and polymorphism and that's just not available in C.

What is allowed and will in fact work is

```
void handleA ( typeA * value );

// ...

struct B bValue = { ... };
handleA((typeA *)&b);
```

This is allowed and safe as both types have the same memory alignment and size, which has nothing to do with having the same fields. Even if they have completely different fields they still can have the same memory alignment and size, which is required for a cast to be standard conform.

Comment: I am afraid that your last example is not safe. `struct B` and `typeA` are not *compatible types* (§6.2.7 p1 in C11/C18 standard), because they are not declared with the same tag. Thus types don't alias (§6.5 p7). It might work, and very likely will with typical compiler, but there is no quarantee that optimizing compiler won't generate invalid code in some specific scenario.

Comment: @user694733 I didn't say the the structures are compatible. The  structures are not. You cannot directly cast one structure to the other one, that will actually result in a compiler error. Aside from the fact the tag requirement only applies when both types are declared in separate translation units, not when they are declared in the same one. My example however was about pointer aliasing (6.3.2.3 p7) which is always allowed as long as both types follow the same alignment rules, otherwise it is undefined.

Comment: You are right about pointer *conversions* (which §6.3.2.3 p7 is about, not aliasing): Everything is OK as long as `handleA` only copies or compares pointers. But as soon as pointer is dereferenced, accessing `value` as `typeA` when it is actually `struct B` is UB, because types are not compatible and neither is member of another (as listed in §6.5 p7).

Comment: @user694733 That's not how I read the standard, sorry. But you are free to write a better answer.

Answer (score 7):

Yes of course! It's just like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef int value_t;
typedef value_t data_t;

int main()
{
    data_t i = 1;
    printf("%d\n", i);

    return 0;
}
```

You can `typedef` as many times as you like.

Comment: I am uncertain whether this actually answers the question, because it's unclear to me what the OP is actually trying to ask.  Inasmuch as the question is somehow about structs, however, this would probably be a better answer to the question if it used a struct type for the typedefs instead of `int`.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question. That can't be done if you want `typedef` multiple things with the same name, that will raise a *conficting type error*. However, you can use `#define` and `#undef` instead to *define* multiple times.